# How to assign the oldest columns in python

Tags: python, pandas

Assume I have df whose record is datetime like this

```
  A          B
2010/1/1  2013/3/1
2014/2/1  2012/1/3
```

I would like to assign new columns which is the oldest and latest column in A and B

like

```
  A         B       oldest    latest
2010/1/1  2013/3/1  2010/1/1  2013/3/1
2014/2/1  2012/1/3  2013/3/1  2014/2/1
```

How can I get this result?

I tried

df.assign(oldest = min(df.A,df.B))

It didnt work well.How can  I get this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you were almost there:

```
In [87]: df.assign(oldest=df[['A','B']].min(1), latest=df[['A','B']].max(1))
Out[87]:
          A         B    oldest    latest
0  2010/1/1  2013/3/1  2010/1/1  2013/3/1
1  2014/2/1  2012/1/3  2012/1/3  2014/2/1
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `df.min` and `df.max`:

```
df['oldest'] = df.min(axis=1)
df['latest'] = df.max(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can using `describe`

```
pd.concat([df,df.T.describe().iloc[4:].T],1)
Out[703]: 
           A          B      first       last
0 2010-01-01 2013-03-01 2010-01-01 2013-03-01
1 2014-02-01 2012-01-03 2012-01-03 2014-02-01
```